# javascript class props

Tags: javascript

I have a class defined like this (scheme) :

```
myClass = BaseClass.extend({
    method1 : function(){ ...},
    method2 : function(){ ...}
});
```

How can I call method2 from method1? something like:

```
myClass = BaseClass.extend({
    method1 : function(){ method2(); },
    method2 : function(){ ...}
});
```

Comment: is `extend` method part of javascript?

Comment: @sv_in - `.extend` is not built into javascript. People generally role their own class systems or use an existing one. I tend to use to the one by John Resig (of jQuery fame): http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need scope:

```
this.method2();
```